# Keyboard signals and foldp in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm trying to make a text field that submits its input by pressing Enter and is cleared by Escape.

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (flow, down, show)
import Signal exposing ((<~), (~))
import Graphics.Input.Field exposing (noContent, defaultStyle, field)
import String
import Keyboard

main = Signal.map view (Signal.foldp step init signals)

signals = (,,) <~ box.signal
                ~ Signal.sampleOn Keyboard.enter box.signal
                ~ escape

escape = Keyboard.isDown 27

box = Signal.mailbox noContent

init = (noContent, noContent, False)

view (text, query, clear) =
    flow down
        [ field defaultStyle (Signal.message box.address) "Enter text" text
        , show (String.words query.string)
        ]

step (text, query, clear) _ =
    case clear of
        False -> (text, query, clear)
        True -> (noContent, noContent, clear)
```

This produces an empty field only while holding Escape and reverts to whatever was entered when Escape is released.

Trying to understand why this is the case lead me to a smaller example:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Signal
import Char
import String
import Keyboard

main = Signal.map show input

input = Signal.foldp step "" (Signal.map2 (,) Keyboard.presses escapeDown)

escapeDown = Keyboard.isDown 27

step (keyCode, esc) string =
    case esc of
        True -> ""
        False -> string ++ keyToString keyCode

keyToString = String.fromChar << Char.fromCode
```

The accumulated string of characters is emptied on pressing Escape but releasing it results in a string of a single (last entered) character.

From what I understand, `Keyboard.isDown` signal is triggered while holding and on key release. So how can I clear the field persistently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The reason you see this behaviour

When you create a signal of pairs (`Signal (KeyCode,Bool)`) out of two signals (`Signal KeyCode`/`Signal Bool`), that signal of pairs will update every time of of the signals update. So the value of `Signal.map2 (,) Keyboard.presses escapeDown` over time might be:

```
(0,False), (97,False), (98,False), (98,True), (98,False)
^          ^ press 'a' ^ press 'b'  ^          ^ release escape
program start                       press escape
```

When you press escape, the pair of values changes and your `foldp` updates to the empty string. When you release escape the pair of values changes again, so `foldp` updates again, finds the `False` value, therefore appends the last character you pressed to the empty string.

## Solution

In this case you're really interested in the event when escape is pressed, but not when it `isDown`. Instead of creating a pair of the signals, it is in this case better to `merge` the signals. To do so they need to be of the same type. Here's an example:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Signal exposing ((<~))
import Char
import String
import Keyboard

type Input = KeyPress Keyboard.KeyCode | EscapePress

main = Signal.map show output

presses = KeyPress <~ Signal.filter ((/=) 27) 0 Keyboard.presses
escapePress = always EscapePress <~ escapeDown
input = Signal.merge escapePress presses

output = Signal.foldp step "" input

escapeDown = Keyboard.isDown 27

step input string =
    case input of
        EscapePress -> ""
        KeyPress keyCode -> string ++ keyToString keyCode

keyToString = String.fromChar << Char.fromCode
```

With a union type `Input`, we represent the different inputs to the program. The presses are wrapped in the `KeyPress` constructor of the union type. The escape button is represented with the other constructor `EscapePress`. Now you have two signals of the same type, which you can `merge`. In your `step` function you pattern match on the constructors of your `Input`, and handle the familiar cases.
Note that I'm filtering the `Keyboard.presses` signal so you don't get a `KeyPress` event from pressing down, holding down or letting go of the escape key.